# complie dll but appear error LNK2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I implement a C++ function as DLL with vs2013. But I have linker error (error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup) building to the dll. I have proper setup and not sure what is wrong. The code is very simple, but I don't know why it can't be built successfully.

Demoone.h

```
#ifndef _Demo_H_
#define _Demo_H_
#ifdef LIBDLL
#define LIBDLL extern "C" _declspec(dllimport)
#else
#define LIBDLL extern "C" _declspec(dllexport)
#endif
LIBDLL int Add(int plus1, int plus2);
#endif
```

Demoone.cpp

```
#include "Demoone.h"
int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return (a + b);
}
```

update：

I modified the header file as bellow

```
#ifndef _Demo_H_
#define _Demo_H_
extern "C" int Add (int a , int b);
#endif
```

and add an def file

```
LIBRARY "Dllmaketwo"
EXPORTS
Add @ 1
```

The same linker error (error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup) also appeared.

Comment: see msdn about how to build dll.

Comment: perhaps you need a .def file as well.

Comment: @marshalcraft I tried the .def file and it doesn't work (the same error).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use load-time linking in the project that uses the DLL you need to link against the .lib produced by the DLL project build.

You can do that with:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "dllproject.lib")
```

Or by adding the .lib to the additional dependencies line in the project settings under Linker->Input. You may also need to mess with the library search path, either in the VC++ Directories page or in the Linker->General page.

Comment: Question said this is problem building the dll, not linking the built dll.

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifndef _Demo_H_
#define _Demo_H_
#ifdef LIBDLLIMPORT //Changed here
#define LIBDLL extern "C" _declspec(dllimport)
#else
#define LIBDLL extern "C" _declspec(dllexport)
#endif
LIBDLL int Add(int plus1, int plus2);
#endif
```

You should not use a same name in `#ifdef` and `#define`,

Did you setup you project correctly? And you should not write a `main()' function in it.

[image]

Comment: @balthasar As you mentioned `external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup)`, did you setup you project correctly? See my updated answer.

Comment: I'm sure setup my project correctly, and error information mentioned the file LIBCMTD.lib(crt0.obj)

Comment: And the same code can run successfully on my friend's computer; it is confused me.

Comment: @balthasar Did you copy the entire solution to your friend's computer? I still  think that you did not setup you project correctly. Try to Google `LIBCMTD.lib(crt0.obj)  error (error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup)` to find a solution.